# Python Converting column of object to dates

Tags: python, pandas

[image]
this continues , already cleaned the data removed missing vars, looked around and could not find  a solution, thank you

```
datetime_str =fires.ALARM_DATE[1]
print(datetime_str)
```

outputs   ->  2007-10-22 00:00:00

want to convert the column using

```
fires['CONT_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(fires['CONT_DATE'], format ='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>
[image]

Comment: What do you expect the output to be?

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: What's your pandas version? I'm not able to reproduce your error.

Comment: panda version 1.3.4 , result im expecting is to convert the strings into dates so i can order/ take differences etc,

Comment: looks like you might have some invalid date string. sort this column ascending and check your dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no mistake in your method of use. The real mistake is because of "pandas.tslib.OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp:"

[Timestamp Limitations](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-timestamp-limits)

[pandas.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

> If 'coerce', then invalid parsing will be set as NaT.

```py
pd.to_datetime(date_col_to_force, errors = 'coerce')
```